# Flutter package for Blockchain BFT consensus between app users

Tags: flutter, blockchain

I am looking for suggestion before I could plan / design an open source flutter package which enable developers to introduce distributed consensus to their application (basically a blockchain within mobile phones) along with their existing backend stack.

This package would work along with existing backend to generate identity, participate in validation of transaction, and store a copy of chain within their device.  Later I am planning to use pluggable encryption based on developer’s need for enhanced security.

Keeping in mind of the best consensus as Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerant but PBFT/BFT has resource intensive PoW to do consensus which phones can't be, I am planning to implement PBFT based on technique explained in “Elastico” paper (review/summary is attached here [1]).

This is just an initial idea rolling in my mind for few hours now. I need to realise the feasibility this technique inside a mobile phone to form a network.

[1] https://muratbuffalo.blogspot.com/2018/03/paper-review-secure-sharding-protocol.html

Why do you want to build this

This package would help devs to integrate features of blockchain to their centralised app stack without rebuilding their backend. Talking about application part, consider situations which involve decision making and forming opinions, supply chain management, data provenance (integrating with IPFS)

Development of the plugin will take some real effort and time.
Not having done any serious feasibility study on the project but I believe this plugin will be useful for a longer run. 
 If there are some suggestions based on your experience in plugin development, pl share it here.

Comment: Folks on Ethereum Stack Exchange can provide a better view to this question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll put it there